# SQL based full text search for given args within group of rows

Tags: sql, database, oracle, search, oracle12c

I'm trying to search for specific data in the database table (Oracle 12c). I want to search for specific texts in row groups. Each group have specific ID, so I would like to get ID of the group if **all** of the searching arguments can be found.

I prepared sample table but with some simplifications:
- In real table there is more than 20 columns and millions of rows.
- I converted real values to some shorter version like a or b, in real table there are VARCHAR(500) columns
- There can be thousands of rows in the same group (same ID)
- The search have to be fast, so manipulating too much of this data or many nested queries might not be an option

Sample Table:

```
+----+----+---+---+----+
| ID | A  | B | C | D  |
+----+----+---+---+----+
|  1 | aq | a | a | a  |
|  1 | a  | a | c | ad |
|  1 | a  | a | a | a  |
|  2 | a  | a | a | a  |
|  2 | a  | a | a | a  |
|  2 | a  | a | a | a  |
|  3 | a  | a | a | a  |
|  3 | a  | a | a | a  |
|  3 | a  | d | a | a  |
+----+----+---+---+----+
```

Sample Cases:

```
+------+-------------+-----------+
| Case |  Searching  |  Expected |
+------+-------------+-----------+
|    1 | `q` and `c` | [1]       |
|    2 | `a` and `d` | [1, 3]    |
|    3 | `a` and `q` | [1]       |
|    4 | `a`         | [1, 2, 3] |
+------+-------------+-----------+
```

Case 1:
ID = 1 - matching q and c in two rows
Result = Row [1]

```
+----+----+---+---+----+
| ID | A  | B | C | D  |
+----+----+---+---+----+
|  1 | aq | a | a | a  | <-- q
|  1 | a  | a | c | ad | <-- c
|  1 | a  | a | a | a  |
|  2 | a  | a | a | a  |
|  2 | a  | a | a | a  |
|  2 | a  | a | a | a  |
|  3 | a  | a | a | a  |
|  3 | a  | a | a | a  |
|  3 | a  | d | a | a  |
+----+----+---+---+----+
```

Case 2:
ID = 2 - doesn't have `d` anywhere
Result: Rows [1, 3]

```
+----+----+---+---+----+
| ID | A  | B | C | D  |
+----+----+---+---+----+
|  1 | aq | a | a | a  | <-- a
|  1 | a  | a | c | ad | <-- a, d
|  1 | a  | a | a | a  | <-- a
|  2 | a  | a | a | a  | <-- a
|  2 | a  | a | a | a  | <-- a
|  2 | a  | a | a | a  | <-- a
|  3 | a  | a | a | a  | <-- a
|  3 | a  | a | a | a  | <-- a
|  3 | a  | d | a | a  | <-- a, d
+----+----+---+---+----+
```

Case 3:
ID = 1, matching q and c in single row
Result: Row [1]

```
+----+----+---+---+----+
| ID | A  | B | C | D  |
+----+----+---+---+----+
|  1 | aq | a | a | a  | <-- a, q
|  1 | a  | a | c | ad | <-- a
|  1 | a  | a | a | a  | <-- a
|  2 | a  | a | a | a  | <-- a
|  2 | a  | a | a | a  | <-- a
|  2 | a  | a | a | a  | <-- a
|  3 | a  | a | a | a  | <-- a
|  3 | a  | a | a | a  | <-- a
|  3 | a  | d | a | a  | <-- a
+----+----+---+---+----+
```

Case 4:
We have `a` everywhere
Result: Rows [1, 2, 3]

```
+----+----+---+---+----+
| ID | A  | B | C | D  |
+----+----+---+---+----+
|  1 | aq | a | a | a  | <-- a
|  1 | a  | a | c | ad | <-- a
|  1 | a  | a | a | a  | <-- a
|  2 | a  | a | a | a  | <-- a
|  2 | a  | a | a | a  | <-- a
|  2 | a  | a | a | a  | <-- a
|  3 | a  | a | a | a  | <-- a
|  3 | a  | a | a | a  | <-- a
|  3 | a  | d | a | a  | <-- a
+----+----+---+---+----+
```

Any help appreciated :), thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
SELECT
    ID
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ID,
            RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E, A || B || C || D, ',').EXTRACT('//text()')).GETCLOBVAL(), ',') 
            AS CONSOLIDATED_VALUE
        FROM
            T
        GROUP BY
            ID
    )
WHERE
    CONSOLIDATED_VALUE LIKE '%q%'
    AND CONSOLIDATED_VALUE LIKE '%c%'
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8d5a5458efc3442bbff661a04716f3b3)

Cheers!!

Comment: I have not used `listagg` as it will throw an error when the length of CONSOLIDATED_VALUE > allowed max value of the VARCHAR2

Comment: This is perfect! It nicely avoids the `listagg` limit and in my case, the search is pretty good. Even the performance of CLOB search looks ok in my case. I love your demo! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `listagg` to:

- Concatenate all the columns into one
- Group the rows for each id into one string

Which gives:

```
create table t (
  id int, a varchar2(2), b varchar2(1), c varchar2(1), d varchar2(2)
);

insert into t values (1, 'aq', 'a', 'a', 'a');
insert into t values (1, 'a', 'a', 'c', 'ad');
insert into t values (1, 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a');
insert into t values (2, 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a');
insert into t values (2, 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a');
insert into t values (2, 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a');
insert into t values (3, 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a');
insert into t values (3, 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a');
insert into t values (3, 'a', 'd', 'a', 'a');
commit;

with vals as (
  select t.id, 
         listagg ( a || b || c || d ) 
           within group ( order by a ) str
  from   t
  group  by t.id
)
  select * from vals
  where  str like '%q%'
  and    str like '%c%';

ID   STR              
    1 aaaaaacadaqaaa    

with vals as (
  select t.id, 
         listagg ( a || b || c || d ) 
           within group ( order by a ) str
  from   t
  group  by t.id
)
  select * from vals
  where  str like '%a%'
  and    str like '%d%';

ID   STR              
    1 aaaaaacadaqaaa    
    3 aaaaaaaaadaa
```

Fair warning: This is likely to be slow!

You may be able to mitigate this by placing the `listagg` query in a materialized view.

Also with 20+ columns with some up to 500 characters long, it's likely you'll blow out the character limit for listagg. Unless you've enabled [extended data types](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/extended-data-types-12cR1) to allow 32,767 long varchar2s in SQL.

Comment: Thanks. This is very good solution. I combined this with materialized view option to gain speed, however in my case, the limit of 32767 characters is also to little.

Comment: If you're still hitting the character limit, you can find various workarounds at https://blogs.oracle.com/datawarehousing/managing-overflows-in-listagg